# Running Elementary OS on MacBookPro10,1, get random resolution changes

Tags: ubuntu, elementary-os, macintosh, display, resolution

I recently installed Elementary OS (Ubuntu-based) and every now and then my resolution drops down to a super small size that messes with my mouse-tracking and pretty much makes any application inaccessible, forcing me to restart.

My hardware is that of a MacBookPro10,1, which has a discrete card and an onboard card, so I think it may have to do with a graphics switch?